# Flying on third party booked tickets

Tags: air-travel, tickets, british-airways

My cousin has booked international flights for me with BA through Expedia. I have an email confirmation that is my e-ticket for printing. Do I need to contact either BA or Expedia before I try to check in for the flight? It just seems too easy to me, compared to when I've booked flights myself.

Comment: You might be a bit more specific here - what exactly is your concern? As long as the tickets have your name name on them you should be fine - you might want to see if you can check in online, but that's usually just for convenience and not a necessity.

Comment: I agree with you completely .. it's "hard to believe" how crisp they have it all worked out.  note that you may need to ENTER YOUR PASSPORT NUMBERS "somewhere" -- check that out.

Comment: If you're worried, just give BA customer support a call and check if your ticket reference is valid for the flight.

Answer (score 2):

As @greyshade commented, I don't know what you might be worried about. I've bought tickets for parents, kids, boyfriend and they all worked fine. Admittedly, those were all domestic flights, but I've had international tickets purchased for me by my employer.

Definitely try to access the ticket record via the confirmation number on the British Airways site (BA) before check-in time. They may allow you to pre-enter passport/visa information/contact information/enable alerts/etc.

If it is an international flight, you might be able to check-in but not print boarding passes. At least in the US, they want to see your passport etc. at the ticket counter.